# Closing file after converting xml to csv

Tags: python, xml, csv

Here is my small script ( which is basicaly only basic uses of the module xmltocsv) code in order to convert xml file around (7Mo) to csv.

I have a small issue as this converter xml2csv which a use, does not close the file until i end the script(close my the shell) which cause me some problem after because i use the new csv ( in the same script) to make some process but as it's not completly written on disk, some data are forgotten.

When i end the script manualy, i see on my disk the file size changing by 1ko. Could you tell me how i can completly write the file on disk... like flush all the data procces by the converter.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF8 -*-
import csv
from xmlutils.xml2csv import xml2csv
import datetime
import time

#Declaration du jour

jour = datetime.date.today()

#Conversion du fichier xml en CSV

inputFile = "../source_xml/source-2014-06-03.xml"
output = "../source_csv/drop"+str(jour)+".csv"

converter = xml2csv(inputFile, output , encoding="utf-8")
converter.convert(tag="product",delimiter="|")

with open("../source_csv/drop"+str(jour)+".csv", 'r+') as output:
    read_data = output.read()
output.close
```

I tried to open it with "with open" and close it but it does not work also.

thanks for your help.

Comment: The with block closes the file for you

Comment: Yes thanks I just forgot to remove it from my script. But even you do that it will not write the full file on your disk, always 1ko is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using xmd2csv from knadh-xmlutils, it seems that effectively it never closes the output csv file.

So you should first verify in the python code of xml2csv that the output file is open as `self.output` and not closed like in the version I know. If it is the case, you should follow the `converter.convert(...)` line with

```
converter.output.close()
```

Comment: Many thanks to serge ! I was not far, i have test before your answer converter.close()  but i'm  not good enough with object programming :)

Answer (score 1):

Two points:

1. you forgot the `()` when calling the `close` method.
2. If you `open` a file using the `with` keyword, there's no need to manually close it after the `with` block. Python will make sure that the resource is closed once it is not needed anymore, even if an exception occurs.

[documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-343-the-with-statement)

Comment: Hi, thanks timgeb i forgot to remove the close methof from the script.Actually it does not work even you use with keyword also, always missing some data on the csv. the xml converted is about 7Mo